# Using MacBook as an audio output mixer so I can combine external input and system audio into one common output source?

Tags: macos, audio, 3.5mm

So my case such - I have a gaming console with an audio output and an M1 MacBook, and I want to be able to use built-in Macbook speakers as an audio output for external device (console) while also playing audio from MacOS.

AFAIK speakers and 3.5mm jack are considered different devices in MacOS, so maybe there is any software that allows mixing input from 3.5mm jack to the sound from built-in/bluetooth speakers (using simple aux cable)?

If there is no such programs, do you think it is theoretically possible to do something like this?

Comment: Your question seems overly complex and is one big paragraph: Please read this and edit/adjust your question so we can help you. What is your question? Macs all have audio output. That “Use Mac as an audio output” is not a question. You mention mixing; so do you want to connect both the Xbox and Mac to a common set of speakers?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it.
No, I don't want to use external speakers. By mixing I meant software mixing, like programs that allow you to output audio from different applications (or mic input) to different outputs (headset or speakers) with different volume.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Your cleanup makes sense as well. I reworked your title to better and clearly state your goal “Use Mac as an audio output” is pretty vague but your core question is very valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing input to output directly is not possible natively. You're going to need 3rd party software.

You will also get latency. You will also get the tinny sound of laptop speakers*. You will also quite likely have a headset socket which can only handle mono input [& designed for a cheap headset mic, not line-in].

I don't see it being a great idea, all in all.

Here's a QA with a list of the currently-available software for Mac that can do this. Mainly you get what you pay for - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408600/capture-audio-correctly-while-capturing-video-calls-on-macbook-with-earbuds

The best of these apps [the Rogue Amoeba stuff] will cost more than a cheap set of speakers.

*I've never owned an Apple laptop but we have an M1 iMac here, with supposedly all-singing, all-dancing, Dolby Atmos, 6-channel yada yada… sounds about as good as a pair of $£€ 20 speakers from a supermarket/electrical retailer. I had to use one of those apps mentioned in the linked QA [SoundSource] to push an aggressive EQ curve into it to make it listenable.
(btw, I'm a sound engineer by trade. I'm picky;)

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I'd like to use one audio input/output with both console and macbook (like play games on one device and use discord on the other, perhaps connect to bluetooth headset and use same mic on both devices), so I would also need a hardware mixer with speakers which takes extra space and also costs extra.

Comment: Splitting the mic to two devices wasn't mentioned before - & is just not possible without a mixer [specifically a multi-bus mixer which is not an entry-level consumer device]. I think you're over-reaching. My answer still stands as to the question you actually asked.